# Problema com float e matriz

Tags: c, matriz, float

Tenho de somar os valores que tenham duas ou mais casas decimais porém quando eu coloco por exp: " 1.0 ", ele preenche toda essa fileira automaticamente e pula pra próxima, revisei e não sei por que ta dando erro então agradeço se puder ajudar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main () { setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    float matriz[7][4], soma = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

        for ( int h = 0; h < 4; h++){
            printf("\nInforme o valor da linha %i e coluna %i: ",i,h);
            scanf("%f",&matriz[i][h]);
        }

        system ("cls");

    }

    for (int c = 0; c < 7; c++){
        for ( int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
            soma += matriz[c][k];
        }
    }

    printf("\nO valor é: %.0f\n",soma);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você especificou o locale do programa como português (chamada a `setlocale` na primeira linha). Você precisa entrar o número nesse formato - se você entrar com `1,2` em vez de `1.2` o seu programa deve fazer o que você quer.

Comment: Melhor seria, na minha opinião, deixar o *locale* como pré-definido para *input* e alterá-lo apenas para *output*.

Comment: Legal, mas como eu seto ele apenas pra output ? ( e vlw Carlos, erro bobo de atenção )